# Need help with custom validation for jQuery validation plugin

Tags: jquery

I'm using the jQuery validation plugin found here:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/validate

In my form I have default values saying "Please enter your name" in the name field.  I'd like a custom validation to ensure that a user has not left this when they submit the form.

Here's the jQuery i'm using.... Can someone please help me with the missing code.

Thanks :)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.validator.addMethod('defaultText', function(value, element) {
    // need code to go here!!!
    }, 'Please enter your first name'); 

 $("#commentForm").validate({
     rules: {

     firstname: {
         required: true,
         defaultText: true,
     },
     email: {
         required: true,
         email: true
     }
 },
     messages: {
         firstname: "Please enter your first name",
         email: "Please enter a valid email address"
     }
 });

 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.validator.addMethod("defaultText", function(value, element) {
    return value != element.defaultValue;
}, "");
```

Figured it out....

This makes whatever is in the field by default - not be accepted as valid input!